# not able to upload image in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

i am using selenium and i want to upload a pic in my project directory

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" class="filesborder filesborder-single"><form _ngcontent-c2="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><input _ngcontent-c2="" class="inputfile inputfile-4" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" id="file-5" name="file-5[]" style="opacity: 0;" type="file" accept=".png,.jpg"></form><label _ngcontent-c2="" for="file-5"><div _ngcontent-c2="" class="col-12 mt-2"><h5 _ngcontent-c2="" class="font-weight-bold pt-2 mb-0">Upload Signature</h5><div _ngcontent-c2="" class="info-txt small"> ( Accepted: .JPG and .png, 20 MB)</div></div><div _ngcontent-c2="" class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-left align-items-center mt-2"><div _ngcontent-c2="" class="btn-bordered-browse">browse </div></div></label></div>
```

i am using sends key method..

```
String filepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\FileToUpload\\download.png";
File file = new File(filepath);
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
    utils.ExplicitWaiting.explicitWaitVisibilityOfElement(browsesign, 120);
    browsesign.sendKeys(path);


@FindBy(xpath="//div//form//input[@id='file-5']")
private WebElement browsesign;
```

i get this exception error-:`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (603e78d403504acd56011da02e09a314)] -> xpath: //div//form//input[@id='file-5']] (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`

help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly happen after this? Do you get any exception?

Comment: i getthis exceptional message:- org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (603e78d403504acd56011da02e09a314)] -> xpath: //div//form//input[@id='file-5']] (tried for 120 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: @ankushsingh It seems to me the `browsesign` is not displayed in web, can you try without wait or with different wait condition like `presenceOfElementLocated​(By locator)`.
You can also change the way to find element `xpath="//div//form//input[@id='file-5']"` --> `id ="file-5"` for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

It Seems there is some issue in xPath which you have created.why are you using //div//form//input[@id='file-5'], you can simply use //input[@id='file-5']

Answer (score 0):

Selenium **will not do** file upload and download functionalities, those actions are interacting via **desktop application**. selenium can only do operations which is completely **rely on browser**. you can only click the the buttons such as **upload file, download files**. please use **sikuli** to select files from local storage.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sikuli/sikuli-api -->

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in your case you can only click the button, you **xpath** is

```
//input[@type='file']
```